# How can I optimize read access?

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance, entity-framework, thread-safety

I work on data that is mostly read and I want to perform these works as efficiently as possible, and I need to provide thread-safe access to it.

Any explanations on my problem would be welcome. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this answer in C# 6 Cookbook

Use `ReaderWriterLockSlim` to give multiple-read/single-write access with the capacity to upgrade the lock from `read` to `write`. As an example, say a developer is starting a new project. Unfortunately, the project is understaffed, so the developer has to respond to tasks from many other individuals on the team. Each of the other team members will also ask the developer for status updates on their tasks, and some can even change the priority of the tasks the developer is assigned. The developer is assigned a task via the `AddTask` method. To protect the Developer Tasks collection we use a write lock on `ReaderWriterLockSlim`, calling EnterWrite Lock when adding the task to the DeveloperTasks collection and `ExitWriteLock` when the addition is complete:

```
public void AddTask(DeveloperTask newTask)
{
    try
    {
        Lock.EnterWriteLock();
        // if we already have this task (unique by name)        
        // then just accept the add as sometimes people        
        // give you the same task more than once :)        
        var taskQuery = from t in DeveloperTasks
                        where t == newTask
                        select t;
        if (taskQuery.Count<DeveloperTask>() == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Task {newTask.Name} was added to developer");
            DeveloperTasks.Add(newTask);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        Lock.ExitWriteLock();
    }
}
```

When a project team member needs to know about the status of a task, they call the `IsTaskDone` method, which uses a read lock on the `ReaderWriterLockSlim` by calling `EnterReadLock` and `ExitReadLock`:

```
public bool IsTaskDone(string taskName)
{
    try
    {
        Lock.EnterReadLock();
        var taskQuery = from t in DeveloperTasks
                        where t.Name == taskName
                        select t;
        if (taskQuery.Count<DeveloperTask>() > 0)
        {
            DeveloperTask task = taskQuery.First<DeveloperTask>();
            Console.WriteLine($"Task {task.Name} status was reported.");
            return task.Status;
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        Lock.ExitReadLock();
    }
    return false;
}
```

There are certain managerial members of the team who have the right to increase the priority of the tasks they assigned to the developer. They accomplish this by calling the IncreasePriority method on the Developer. IncreasePriority uses an upgradable lock on `ReaderWriterLockSlim` by first calling the `EnterUpgradeable` Lock method to acquire a read lock, and then, if the task is in the queue, upgrading to a write lock in order to adjust the priority of the task. Once the priority is adjusted,
the write lock is released, which degrades the lock back to a read lock, and that lock is released through a call to `ExitUpgradeableReadLock`:

```
public void IncreasePriority(string taskName)
{
    try
    {
        Lock.EnterUpgradeableReadLock();
        var taskQuery = from t in DeveloperTasks
                        where t.Name == taskName
                        select t;
        if (taskQuery.Count<DeveloperTask>() > 0)
        {
            DeveloperTask task = taskQuery.First<DeveloperTask>();
            Lock.EnterWriteLock(); task.Priority++;
            Console.WriteLine($"Task {task.Name}" + $" priority was increased to {task.Priority}" + " for developer"); Lock.ExitWriteLock();
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        Lock.ExitUpgradeableReadLock();
    }
}
```

Discussion The `ReaderWriterLockSlim` was created to replace the existing `ReaderWriterLock` for a number of reasons:

- `ReaderWriterLock` was more than five times slower than using a
  Monitor.
- Recursion semantics of `ReaderWriterLock` were not standard and were
  broken in some thread reentrancy cases.
- The upgrade lock method is nonatomic in ReaderWriterLock. While the
  `ReaderWriterLockSlim` is only about two times slower than the `Monitor`,
  it is more flexible and prioritizes writes, so in “few write, many read” scenarios, it is more scalable than the `Monitor`.
- There are also methods to determine what type of lock is held as well
  as how many threads are waiting to acquire it. By default, `lock`
  acquisition recursion is disallowed. If you call EnterReadLock twice,
  you get a `LockRecursionException`. You can enable lock recursion by passing a Lock RecusionPolicy.SupportsRecursion enumeration value to the constructor overload of `ReaderWriterLockSlim` that accepts it.
- Even though it is possible to enable lock recursion, it is generally
  discouraged, as it complicates matters and creates issues that are
  not fun to debug.

Answer (score 1):

So the basics of creating a thread

```
//
Threat t = new Thread (My_Function);
// or 
Thread t = new Thread (()=>
{
   //your code here
});
t.start();
```

If you want to make the read thread safe you can use the "lock statement inside the thread on the resources that you want to ensure serial access

```
lock (Read_resource_object)
{
}
```

What lock does is, is the first time code runs over the lock statement it will "lock" the resource until the then of the curly braces. This does not prevent other code from accessing that object, rather, if any other code calls a lock on that resource, that code blocks until the current thread that locked it, unlocks it. Of course be very careful to make sure your don't get a thread lock,which usually occurs if inside your first lock somehow the flow of the code results in trying to lock the same code before it gets unlocked. Other than that I would recomend reading some tutorials on this because mutli threading and thread saftey are difficult and complicated!

Also lookup tasks as well they wrap threads and provide additional functionality.